# Best practice for organizing the R folder inside a package

Tags: r, package

I am working on a few large packages with lots of s3 classes and related methods, and I was wondering how other people are organizing their */R* directory. There seem to be no official guidelines and I could not find any consensus among popular packages. I was wondering what strategies other people use.

for example:

- If you have `genericfun()` for `fancyclass`, do you make an .R file for generic? And where to put `generic.fancyclass`, does it go in *generic.R* or *fancyclass.R*?
- Similarily, where to put custom conditions/exceptions
- logging (f.e. with `futile.logger`) or warnings/messages?
- any other strategies you people use to keep everything organized,
- etc..